# SQL sort records based on condition in many to many relation

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, sql-order-by

I am unable to write SQL to sort records based on condition in many to many relationship. I have table structure `tasks` with many to many table for task dependencies. E.g. Task C can have one or many dependencies on other tasks trough table `task_dependencies`.

- TASKS: id, user_id, status_id, date_due, ...
- TASK_DEPENDENCIES: task_id, dependency_task_id (pivot table)
- Statuses are following: Q-new, G-In progress, L-closed

The idea with task dependencies is that one task can not be started until all his dependency task(s) are closed. I would like to select all user's open tasks. This is easy. But I need to sort them by date_due, but having all the task with dependencies that can not be started yet on the end of result set. Meaning I need to somehow check if all dependency tasks are closed and take this into account when sorting somehow?

I managed to put together one select but this always puts all tasks with dependencies at the end of the record set. But I would like to put tasks with closed dependencies in normal date_due order flow...

```
SELECT 
   T.id, T.description, TD.dependency_task_id, 
   ISNULL(TD.dependency_task_id) AS NoDependency, T.date_due
FROM tasks T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN task_dependencies TD 
  ON T.id = TD.task_id 
WHERE assigned_user_id=1
ORDER BY NoDependency DESC, T.date_due
```

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/894f7/3.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  It uses `OR` in the select statement to see if the `dependency_task_id is null` or if it's `status = 'L'` joining back to the `tasks` table to look that up.

```
SELECT T.id, T.description, TD.dependency_task_id, 
  ISNULL(TD.dependency_task_id) OR t2.status_id = 'L'  AS NoDependency, 
  T.date_due
FROM tasks T 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN task_dependencies TD 
    ON T.id = TD.task_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks t2 
    ON TD.dependency_task_id = T2.id 
WHERE T.assigned_user_id=1
ORDER BY NoDependency DESC, T.date_due
```

- [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/894f7/6)

Comment: Looks better but not perfect. The problem is that the tasks that have multiple dependencies are listed multiple times in the result set... Each task should be on the list only once! If at list one of it's dependencies is still open should be sorted at the end between the tasks that are not ready to be started yet.

Comment: You can look in your SQLfiddle for task with ID 811, it is listed twice. Trying to figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Yeah this now looks like being what I want. The only thing I don't like is that uses nested SELECTs which means it's a lot slower. But I am really not sure if it's possible to do it any other way.

Comment: If you are willing to update your answer with working code in your last comment I will accept your answer.